# JSONP response failing to be stored in a closure

Tags: javascript, ajax, closures, jsonp

I am making an API request via JSONP in order to avoid cross domain error. I want to store the response in a variable which is in a closure (a function expression "module"), which is accessed via two "public methods".

One of these methods, module.store, is the callback used by the API response. The other method updates the p tag with the contents of API response.

After I click "submit" to initiate the API request, I know that the callback is successfully invoked, as I can briefly see the updated display before it disappears.

I think I must be losing the response once the function exits, but the closure should still be able to access the private variable.

If I call the requestJSONP() from within the browser it works.

I am unable to recreate the issue in JS fiddle because it does not like the JSONP request.

HTML:

```
<body>
<header>Wikipedia Viewer</header>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <p>default text</p>
        <form>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addListenerToButton);

//callback for DOM load which adds a click event on the submit button
function addListenerToButton() {

var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

button.addEventListener("click", requestJSONP); 
console.log("addListenerToButton");
};

//advoids cross browser origin error
function requestJSONP(searchTerm) {
    //dynamically create a script tag
    var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    //set url 
    scriptTag.src = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=covfefe&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json&callback=test";
    //append tag to head element 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
    console.log("got to JSONP");
};

function test(data){
        module.store(data);
}

//callback invoked when API sends reponse
var module = (function(){
    var storedValue = [];
console.log("got to module");
    return {
        store: function(val){
            storedValue.push(val);
            console.log("got to module.store");
            displayArray(); 
        },

        retrieve: function(){
            return storedValue;
        },

    }

}());

function displayArray(){
    var stored = module.retrieve(); 
    pTag = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    text = pTag.textContent = stored;

}
```

Comment: jsonp is called from a fresh/global context, there's no closure involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  default behavior (in Chrome at least) is to refresh page, which was clearing stored value. I have overridden this default behavior below:

```
function saveText(event) {
    debugger
    event.preventDefault()
    var userInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

    if (userInput === "") {
        alert("Please enter a search term")
        return 
    }
    requestJSONP(userInput);
    console.log("saveText");
};
```